# Check for and (possibly) remove event from the calendar in Swift using EventKit

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, eventkit

I am looking for a way to check if an event exists already in the calendar before adding it. If it does exist, I would like to remove that event before adding the new version. Here is my createEvent function:

```
func createEvent(eventStore: EKEventStore, title: String, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate, place:String) {
    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
    event.title = title
    event.startDate = startDate
    event.endDate = endDate
    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
    let alarm:EKAlarm = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -60*60*6)
    event.alarms = [alarm]
    event.location = place


    do {

        try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
        savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier
        self.eventSaved = true

    } catch {
        self.eventSaved = false

    }


}
```

Basically I would like to insert this above the saveEvent bit to avoid duplicates. The reason I would prefer to delete the existing event instead of doing nothing is so that if there is a duplicate, the latest version is always added. This is most likely a simple thing to do, but I can't seem to find any information on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to delete the old event.
Just retrieve the old one and replace all the values with the new ones.

In order to achieve that you need to store in your datamodel the eventIdentifier, as you are doing in your example with "savedEventId"

so then instead of always creating a event like in your first line:

```
let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
```

do this instead:

```
let event: EKEvent?
// if I have a previous event identifier i can try to retrieve the event
if let eventIdentifier = savedEventId {
     event = eventStore.eventWithIdentifier(eventIdentifier)
} 
// if i did not find it, then i create a new one
if event == nil {
    event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
}

event.title = title
event.startDate = startDate
event.endDate = endDate
....
```